# Transformer design, 120 Vac to 350 Vdc

Tags: transformer, rectifier

I am trying to design an AC-DC boost converter, from 120 VAC to 350 VDC. I believe the transformer design is giving me a lot of issues.

This is the code that I wrote to find the values that I need.:

```
#1. TRANSFORMER
Vin = 120  # after losses
Vout = 350
Ton = 6e-6
Bmax = 220e-3
Aeff = 353e-6  # effective magnetic cross section, from this datasheet. https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1872305.pdf

Np = (Vin * Ton) / (Bmax * Aeff)
print('Np = ', Np)

Ns = (Vout * Ton) / (Bmax * Aeff)
print('Ns = ', Ns)

##1.2 using formula for inductors
lengthCore = 4e-2
widthCore = 5.4e-2/2

import math
L2 = (Ns*Ns*1.26e-6*math.pi*widthCore*widthCore)/lengthCore

print ("L2 = ", L2)

##1.1 wrt inductance
L1 = (Np*Np*L2)/(Ns*Ns)

print('L1 = ', L1)
```

When I run my circuit I am getting 27 V, which makes no sense.
[image]

[image]

Is something wrong with the formula that I am using because I am using the basic transformer equations for this.

Comment: Try replacing the diode with a different one, for example US1M? R32 is also very low given R36.

Comment: @winny I replaced the resistor with 10k, and I got 80V at the output, but why does changing the resistor affect my output, shouldn't the voltage drop be constant?

Comment: Measure the current through R36 and its subsequent voltage drop.

Comment: Also just for reference, ensure that "VAMPL=120V" of V1 is RMS, not peak or p-p.  It must be RMS if you're getting the expected result, but not all simulation software will interpret "Amplitude" as RMS.  *Typically*, "amplitude" will be peak or peak-to-peak.

Comment: @rdtsc, thank you for pointing that out, I probed the input, it is peak to peak, I will change it into rms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve got a 10 Ohm load.  At the design point of 350 Vdc, this results in 35 Amps. The step-up transformer is about 3:1, so the current into the primary needs to be on the order of 100 Amps. But the 10 ohm resistor on the primary side drops most of the input voltage.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gary, that makes sense, I changed it to 1ohm and now I am getting the required voltage. Thanks a ton!